# java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY when opening the terminal in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, webstorm

I am using WebStorm for an Angular project from past 6 months and suddenly now when I try to access terminal in WebStorm I am getting an error message

> java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY

could not actually understand the cause of this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: such errors may occur if the shell can't be found by specified path (shouldn't be your case) or if the libraries/binaries used by built-in terminal are corrupted/blocked by some process. Try re-installing th IDE - does the issue persist? If yes, try to make sure that IDE installation and configuration folders are excluded from virus scanning, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot lena. it worked after reinstalling the webstorm. When uninstalling make sure to delete all the files from the installation folder else the issue reccur.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the IDE is not finding the correct shell path for your installed git version.

To solve this, go to the `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal` menu and change the Shell path based on the installed git version.

On Windows do:

for 64bit:
`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

for 32bit:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

Don't forget the quotes around the command.

And Linux:

`/usr/bin/zsh`,`/usr/bin/bash` or the Shell path for your system.